# How can I change the bottom margin in res.cls LaTeX file?

Tags: margins, cv, resume

I'm using `\documentclass[margin]{res}`, I can change the `top margin` by using `\topmargin=-.5in`.

But I don't know what to do for bottom margin.

Help?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! One general method for setting document page set-up is to use the [`geometry` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/geometry).  In any case, your question would improved by adding a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Besides what Andrew said, you can use `\textheight 9in` (default) along with `\topmargin` and control the bottom margin. For example `\textheight 9.5in` will reduce bottom margin by 0.5in.

Comment: But to be honest, don't use low lever commands, use the higher level and user friendly interface provided by package `geometry` (as already mentioned`).

Comment: `\usepackage[bottom=3cm]{geometry}` for example

Comment: Is there any news here?

Comment: I find this question to be quite clear and pertinent. In my opinion it should not had been closed. Good answers in the comments of Andrew Swann and user11232, it was helpful for me.